# Can someone explain this Integer modular behavior to me in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

```
*Test> ((3^40) `mod` 3) :: Int
2
*Test> ((3^40) `mod` 3)
0
```

Why is this so? I am using GHCi 7.0.3. If this is not a bug, an explanation of how Integral/Int works in haskell is appreciated, or a link to an explaination.

Thanks.

Comment: The first is an integer overflow, the second result is as expected because `Integer` is used, an arbitrary-precision integer type.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're simply out of range, `3^40` is too big of a number to even fit in a 64-bit int:

```
Prelude> 3^40 :: Int
-6289078614652622815
Prelude> 3^40 :: Integer
12157665459056928801
```

The `Integer` type on the other hand is unbounded and accepts all numbers no matter how big. In your second case (where you got a `0` result) you got a type `Integer` inferred.

Comment: Defaulting rules strike again!

Answer (score 2):

If you on using exponentiation only in the context of modular arithmetic, have a look at the `powerMod` function in the `arithmoi` package:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi

```
import Math.NumberTheory.Powers (powerMod)

test = powerMod 3 40 3
```

`powerMod` reduces the result while computing the exponentiation which should result in less work being done.